# WKWebView use cache only if offline

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swift5

I'm loading a website into a `WKWebView` like so:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://example.com") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy:NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad)

    webView.load(request)
}
```

I'm using the `CachePolicy` to also load the site when offline. But now when my site changes, the web view always loads it from cache. Even if online.

I would expect a cache policy behaviour such as: `LoadElseCacheData` (not the way it is now)

Any idea on how to achieve caching for offline AND always load the new site if available?

When I'm using my web browser, it works as expected. From cache if no changes (304) and reload if changes (200).

Comment: It seems to me that you are abusing the cache as a permanent (offline) store? This isn't what caches are supposed to do.

Comment: @idmean how else would you suggest should I implement the desired behaviour then?